# Dealing With Binary / Bitshifts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation

I am trying to perform some bitshift operations and dealing with binary numbers in JavaScript.

Here's what I'm trying to do. A user inputs a value and I do the following with it:

```
// Square Input and mod with 65536 to keep it below that value
var squaredInput = (inputVal * inputVal) % 65536;
// Figure out how many bits is the squared input number
var bits = Math.floor(Math.log(squaredInput) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
// Convert that number to a 16-bit number using bitshift.
var squaredShifted = squaredInput >>> (16 - bits);
```

As long as the number is larger than 46, it works. Once it is less than 46, it does not work.
I know the problem is the in bitshift. Now coming from a C background, I know this would be done differently, since all numbers will be stored in 32-bit format (given it is an `int`). Does JavaScript do the same (since it `var`s are not typed)?

If so, is it possible to store a 16-bit number? If not, can I treat it as 32-bits and do the required calculations to assume it is 16-bits?

Note: I am trying to extract the middle 4-bits of the 16-bit value in `squaredInput`.

Another note: When printing out the var, it just prints out the value without the padding so I couldn't figure it out. Tried using `parseInt` and `toString`.

Thanks

Comment: Try `(squaredInput >> 16) & 0xffff`

Comment: I was going to suggest a bitmask as well, I've found those useful.

Comment: In JavaScript, all number are 64bit-floats. Only for dealing with [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) they will be converted to 32-bit signed integers.

Comment: @Pointy still produces the same problem. Anything under 46 does not work.

Comment: How can I print out `squaredInput` WITH the padding? So the whole stored number.

Comment: Oh sorry, **durr**; try `(squaredInput >> 8) & 0xffff` - no wait it still doesn't work; wow maybe my brain is broken

Comment: So `squaredInput` is just a 32-bit signed integer? Or is it 64-bit? I can figure out the shifting stuff once someone answers this. I do not know what `squaredInput` is.

Comment: Well JavaScript kind-of goes back and forth; really numbers are always floats, but for the integer/bitwise stuff (and some other things) it truncates them to 32-bit integers.  Doing `~~squaredInput` for example forces it to be an integer value. I'm still confused here however so take that with a grain of salt ...

Comment: OK 45*45 is 2025. `(2025 >> 8) & 0xffff` gives me 7, which I think is correct.  Do you agree?

Comment: Hmm.. why are you shifting by 8? And doesn't that shift 8 `1`'s upfront making it all `1's then just masking it with `1`s which doesn't mak ea difference? How is that a 7? Why did it only take 3 bits out of the, umm 64-bit or whatever JS stores its values with?

Comment: I shift by 8 first to get rid of the low 8 bits, and then and with a mask of 16 bits. The shift by 8 truncates to 32 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
function get16bitnumber( inputVal ){
   return ("0000000000000000"+(inputVal * inputVal).toString(2)).substr(-16);
}
```

This function returns last 16 bits of `(inputVal*inputVal)` value.By having binary string you could work with any range of bits.

Comment: Why do you put 16 0's in the beginning?

Comment: for padding . `get16bitnumber` will always return 16-length binary string, with leading zeros

Comment: @Nayefc I have updated my answer, that might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bitshifting in JS if you don't absolutely have to. The [specs](http://es5.github.com/#x8.5) mention at least four number formats

- IEEE 754
- Int32
- UInt32
- UInt16

It's really confusing to know which is used when.

For example, `~` applies a bitwise inversion while converting to Int32. UInt16 seems to be used only in `String.fromCharCode`. Using bitshift operators converts the operands to either UInt32 or to Int32.

In your case, the right shift operator `>>>` [forces conversion to UInt32](http://es5.github.com/#x11.7.3).
When you type

```
a >>> b
```

this is what you get:

```
ToUInt32(a) >>> (ToUInt32(b) & 0x1f)
```